Setting highlight for ColorColumn in neovim using Lua
In vim, I can do:
set colorcolumn=80
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=red guibg=red

and it works fine.
I am trying to achieve the same thing in NeoVim, using lua script.
I have tried various things, but so far no luck. Some of the things I tried, like shown in How to override color scheme in neovim lua config file?:
vim.opt.colorcolumn = '81' -- This line works fine! 
vim.cmd([[ highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=red guibg=red ]]) -- but this does not
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "ColorColumn", { ctermbg='Red', bg='Red' }) -- neither this one

What am I doing wrong?
NeoVim version: 0.10.0
Platform: Ubuntu

What happens if you use :hi ColorColumn ctermbg=red guibg=red interactively?

Thanks for the comment. It correctly sets the 81st column red as expected.

And what happens if you use :lua vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "ColorColumn", { ctermbg='Red', bg='Red' }) interactively?

good point. If I do it interactively, it works. Intriguing.! How come it does not work from lua file tho ? I am pretty sure lua config files work as I have bunch of other stuff in there, including plugins etc.
